# How to add a custom font to an ExtJS app?

Tags: extjs

colleagues!

Please suggest, how to add a custom font to ExtJS so, that it would be loaded together with the applicaton, **in case the user doesn't have this font installed in his system**?

What folder must it be loaded to, and where and how should it be included?

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add new font files to `myApp\resources\fonts` and add corresponding CSS rules to `sass\etc\all.scss` (thanks to scebotari66) like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Pragmatica;
    src: url(fonts/Pragmatica.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

*If you need your font before ExtJS upload its files you can add CSS rule to custom folder like `myApp\resources\css\app.css` and include `app.css` within `myApp\index.html` like  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/app.css">`. It works well with Sencha CMDs `sencha app build`.*

Comment: I place the font files the in the same folder that you do, but I don't like the idea of an additional css file, instead, I place the rules inside `sass/etc/all.scss` file.

Comment: @scebotari66, I think yes, its more suitable place. Just in my case I store in this file some other CSS rules (inc. fonts) in this file that I need before ExtJS upload all its files.

Comment: like this it makes sense. I also have one css file for this purpose (splash screen rules), but for the sake of the fonts only, it's an overkill. Also when including the font rules in scss you should get rid of `../` in front of the path, because the rules are merged in the App-all.css files, which is loaded from the `resources` folder.

Comment: @scebotari66 Thanks! Edited answer. And since I cannot reward you within this question I've upvoted one of your answers.