# Custom fonts not applied to the text in html editor in ExtJs

Tags: extjs6-classic

I want to use some custom fonts in my HTML editor. So, for that I've added some fonts name in font families in HTML editor.
So, when I've tried to apply that fonts to the text it was not applied correctly.

For resolving that issue I've gone through the following solution:
[How to add a custom font to an ExtJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462193/how-to-add-a-custom-font-to-an-extjs-app)

But this solution not working for me.

So, can you please help me out?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding the font directly in the index.html file?

Comment: Thanks, @ground_Call for your response. But, actually I've achieved it another way. I've created a CSS file with the font face and in the href of the link provide the path of the created CSS file and that link I've included in index.html and its works for me.